# Program to monitor GPU temp/usage for AMD cards?

Tags: software-recommendation, radeon

Is there a program that can display the active clock speeds, GPU usage and temperature of AMD graphics cards? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**AMD Catalyst**

With the AMD catalyst/fglrx drivers is the aticonfig: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Aticonfighelp

> ATI Overdrive (TM) options:
>
> The following options are used to get
>   and set current and peak, core  and memory clock information as well
>   as read the current temperature of  adapters...

Answer (score 0):

Super simple python script to monitor gpu usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import os

while True:
    os.system("aticonfig --adapter=0 --od-getclocks | grep -i GPU")
    time.sleep(3)
```

place it in a python file (ex. gpuusage.py) and run it in a terminal (ex. python3 gpuusage.py)